# Vue.js computed on nested arrays

Tags: knockout.js, vue.js

I come from a Knockout.js background and I've been thinking of trying out Vue.js for my future projects. One thing that confuses me is using computed functions on nested arrays of data.

Lets say we get this data structure from an ajax call "/api/getProject/".

```
{
    projectID: 23,
    phases: [
        {
            phaseID: 23,
            activities: [
                {activityID : 23, start: "date", end : "date"},
                {activityID : 23, start: "date", end : "date"}
            ]
        },
        {
            phaseID: 24,
            activities: [
                {activityID : 23, start: "date", end : "date"},
                {activityID : 23, start: "date", end : "date"}
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

For this, I would want a few computed variables. The first, would be the duration of each activity. Then, I would want a computed for the total duration of each phase. And finally a computed for the total duration of the project.

With KO.js the way I did this was to create classes for each data point and put the computed functions in each class. Ex.

```
    var Project = function(obj){
    var self = this;

    self.projectID = ko.observable(obj.projectID);

    var mapped = mapArray(obj.phases, i => new Phase(i));
    self.phases = ko.observableArray(mapped);

    self.computed = {
        total : ko.computed(() => {
            var total = 0;
            for(var phase of self.phases())
                total += phase.computed.total();
            return total;
        }),
    }
}

var Phase = function(obj){
    var self = this;

    self.phaseID = ko.observable(obj.phaseID);

    var mapped = mapArray(obj.activities, i => new Activity(i));
    self.activities = ko.observableArray(mapped);

    self.computed = {
        total : ko.computed(() => {
            var total = 0;
            for(var act of self.activities())
                total += act.computed.duration();
            return total;
        }),
    }
}

var Activity = function(obj){
    var self = this;

    self.activityID = ko.observable(obj.activityID);
    self.start = ko.observable(obj.start);
    self.end = ko.observable(obj.end);

    self.computed= {
        duration: ko.computed(() => {
        return end - start;
        }),
    }
}
```

And then do.

```
 $.getJSON("/api/getProject", function (data, status, xhr) {
        VM.project = new Project(data);
    }),
```

Here are some of the things I've read and considered and why I couldn't get them to work.

"Use components Project, Phase, Activity with each having their own computed properties" - from what I understand, components can't read data from other components and my data comes all in one call so how would I set the data in each component? Most answers just fill the data with hard coded values which is not gonna be the case most of the time.

Any help is appreciated. I understand I might be looking at this the wrong way, so if I can change how my data is delivered or the way I think about Vue.js; I am willing to do that.

Comment: Knockout does not have what Vue has - state management via Vuex. That's where you keep your data in a centralized fashion so your various components can access it. https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for global state management, so you need to use Vuex.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html

Once you have Vuex installed, you'll create a store (which represents the current state of your application) then you'll create an [action](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html) that sends an asynchronous API request (the ajax request) and updates the store accordingly. Every component that depends on the data received in this API call will react to this update. You can optionally have a [Vuex getter](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html), which behaves exactly as a regular component getter but is available across all your components.

---

> The idea is that the dates of each activity are editable.

There is no secret about editing nested properties. You just need to update the whole object in order to keep the reactivity.

Here is a complete example:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    phases: [
      {
        phaseId: 1,
        activities: [
          { activityId: 1, start: 1, end: 6 },
          { activityId: 2, start: 5, end: 9 },
        ],
      },
      {
        phaseId: 2,
        activities: [
          { activityId: 3, start: 10, end: 16 },
          { activityId: 4, start: 14, end: 19 },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  mutations: {
    setDuration (state, {phaseId, activityId, start, end}) {
      const phase = state.phases.find(x => x.phaseId === phaseId);
      state.phases = [
        ...state.phases.filter(x => x !== phase),
        {
          ...phase,
          activities: [
            ...phase.activities.filter(x => x.activityId !== activityId),
            { activityId, start, end }
          ],
        },
      ];
    },
  },
});

const example = {
  data() {
    return {
      phaseId: null,
      activityId: null,
      start: null,
      end: null
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapState(['phases']),
    phasesFormated() {
      return JSON.stringify([...this.phases].sort((a, b) => a.phaseId - b.phaseId), null, 2);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    ...Vuex.mapMutations(['setDuration']),
    updatePhase() {
      this.setDuration({
        phaseId: parseInt(this.phaseId),
        activityId: parseInt(this.activityId),
        start: parseInt(this.start),
        end: parseInt(this.end),
      });
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <div>
        Phase ID:
        <input type="text" v-model="phaseId">
        <br />
        Activity ID:
        <input type="text" v-model="activityId">
        <br />
        Start:
        <input type="text" v-model="start">
        <br />
        End:
        <input type="text" v-model="end">
      </div>
      <button type="button" v-on:click="updatePhase">update</button>
      <pre style="margin-right: 1rem">{{ phasesFormated }}</pre>    
    </div>
  `,
};

const app = new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app',
  components: { example },
  template: `
    <div v-cloak>
      <h1>app</h1>
      <example></example>
    </div>
  `
});
```

Reconstructing the whole object may get a bit messy, tho. That's why people that use state management libraries (Vuex, Redux etc) often normalize the data.

The docs of Redux library have [a nice example of what data normalization is](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape), and the creator of Vue has [an interesting post on the subject](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuex-best-practices-for-complex-objects/10143/2) as well.

Comment: i've looked at vuex store and it doesn't really solve my problem. The idea is that the dates of each activity are editable. This means the duration (which is a computed property will change) and that will in result affect the duration of the phase and that will affect the duration of the project.

My question really concerns itself with nested computed properties. I've done a lot of digging and the nobody really addresses this issue.